# Adding an Associated doc from another doc

Tags: alfresco

I want to build a model in alfresco that represents translation in multiple languages of a file and each translation should be a separate document. The approach I've followed is creating 2 custom models, one for the original doc and one for the translation with translation-specific metadata, and defining association between the original doc and its translation. But how to make the user able to create a new translation from the original doc ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box action in the share documentlibrary webinterface to create associations. I think you ll have to create your own custom share documentlibrary action button that associates the 2 documents.

See for example this tutorial on how to create custom share actions: http://blog.arvixe.com/add-custom-action-in-alfresco-share/